# How to link to a list item using object model Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010

I have 2 lists.

List1 (Customer) is populated with items.........

List2 (Orders) I am busy populating, in List2 I have a Hyperlink field (customer) which (should) link to List1

So when the user is browsing List2 (Orders) I want him/her to be able to click on the customer field link and get taken to the custom list item in List1 (Customer)

I'm using object model to populate List2, I'm trying this without luck:

```
// Items[0] = the SPListItem for my Customer List Item
SPListItem item = items[0];

item.Url.ToString(); // this returns - Lists/[MyOrderListName]/1735_.000
```

However setting the value of the order list item like this:

```
oListItem["PLANS"] = siteURL + customerLink + ", " + customerName;
```

Gives me: http://myServer.com/Lists/[MyOrderListName]/1735_.000]

This is not the correct url to the list item, so how can I format the link so it really points to the list item?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE: The short version**

What is the URL for a list item in a list?

Because -

```
SPListItem item = items[0];
item.Url.ToString();
```

Does not produce a valid browsable link for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about: http://site/web/list/DispForm.aspx?ID=[your item's ID] ?

Comment: Looks good, let me try it :)

Comment: Works like a charm, and I spotted a dynamic way to get the display form URL (its relative) item.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl